# Difference between :class and :id , under what circumstances would we generally use <%= %> and <% %> in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, tags

when we make use of rails helpers like form_form, form_tag, many a times especially when we need to use Javascript using the :html option that comes along with these helpers we give `:id => "some_value" and :class => "some_value"`. I just wanted to understand what separates the "id" and "class" from usability perspective. This would help me to better decide when I would need to use either of these options and when would I have to use both of them.

Also,

I just wanted to know exactly understand under what circumstances do we use `<%= %>` and when would we use `<% %>` wrt Rails. I have seen their use in a variety of circumstances so far.

It would be great if you could answer these questions with relevant e.g.'s,

Many thanks for your time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'class' vs 'id' question is really referring to CSS best practices. Here's some info on that: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

The `<%= %>` ERB tag outputs the result of the expression in the tag, for example...

```
<%= ['hello', 'world'].join(' ') %>
```

Would be replaced with the string "hello world"

Lets say you want to set a variable for later use, for that you would use the `<% %>` tags because you don't want to output the result yet. Eg:

```
<% my_var = "test" %>
```

This outputs nothing, but does set the `my_var` variable for later use. If you used the `<%=` by mistake...

```
<%= my_var = "test" %>
```

That tag would be replaced with "test" in the resulting rendered page, which probably isnt what you wanted to do in that case. Another common use for `<% %>` tags are loops.

```
<% ['item1','item2','item3'].each do |item| %>
  <li><%= item %></li>
<% end %>
```

Which would result in:

```
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
```

I hope this helps clear up some of your questions!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I just wanted to ask are the `<%= %> and the `<% %>` tags coined by any names in Rails?..

Answer (score 1):

Another thing in Rails is that after 3.0 release helpers like `form_for` etc uses `<%= %>`, because it add tags for you in the background. (So since `.each` only prints the text/code in the block, it doesn't require the `=`)

So `<%= %>` evaluates the code in between, and then prints the result to your page, and `<% %>` just runs the code.

If you really need to print something within `<% %>`, use [#concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat)